# problem in generic function

Tags: java

`enter code here`hello, everyone, can somebody explain what is my problem in this function:

```
public class Summer{
 public <X,Y> Y[] sum(X[] inArr, Y first, SumFunction<Y,X> f, Y[] outArr){
  for(int i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++){
   outArr[i] = f.op(inArr[i], first); //here I have problem
   first = outArr[i];
  }
  return outArr;
 }
}
```

I receive an error:

```
The method op(Y, X) in the type SumFunction<Y,X> is not applicable for the arguments (X, Y)
```

I need to use this function, how can I do this, thanks for any suggestions

Comment: post the code of the op() method

Comment: That's what I've commented first, but if you take a look at the error, I think that you have the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call f.op(first, inArray[i]).
The op() method of SumFunction seems to take  an Y as the first argument, and an X as the second.

Answer (score 0):

My quick guess would be that the method **op** in **SumFunction** has the following signature:

```
Y op(Y, X);
```

But you first pass the X argument and then the Y. So, revert arguments in the method call, so it would be:

```
outArr[i] = f.op(first, inArr[i]);
```

However, it would be better, if you posted the code for the **SumFunction** class.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
f.op(X value1, Y value2);
```

Double check if this matches the declaration `SumFunction#op`. It looks like, `SumFunction#op` expects the arguents in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `op()` function is expecting `f.op(first, inArr[i])` instead